# Hide Action Bar for Splash Screen

Tags: android, android-actionbar, splash-screen

I'm trying to create splash screen without action bar.
Firstly before created splash screen, action bar in main activity and  when I create splash screen, action bar comes to splash screen and main activity is full screen. I searched method like `getwindow()`, `getActionBar()`, but when I use these method program says to me unfortunately stopped. So what I'm missing?

How can I avoid `actionBar` in splash screen?

My code:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_item);
    
    Thread th=new Thread(){
        public void run(){
            try {
                sleep(4000);
                Intent intent=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SplashScreen.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
    th.start();
}
```

MANİFEST:

```
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
     <activity
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SPLASHSCREEN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: can you post stacktrace?

Comment: Duplicate question! You can found the solution this:

[Solution: Hide ActionBar][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16823648/2826046

Comment: possible duplicate of [splash screen application and hide action bar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823049/splash-screen-application-and-hide-action-bar)

Comment: Worked for me : `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`
Add this to your activity tag

Answer (score 5):

First, import the support library in the top of your app:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
```

and change your code as follows:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.splash_item);
    getSupportActionBar().hide();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `AppCompat` for being supported for all versions:

```
<activity 
android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
```

Answer (score 1):

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Put that before your setContentView(...), should get the job done.

Comment: I put but says to unfortunately stopped @The Hungry Androider

Comment: This dosen't work with Android 5.0 it hides only the status bar

Answer (score 1):

For Android 3.0 or higher use [ActionBarAPI#hide](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#hide())
For lower versions you will need to use Android Support Library. 
Use ActionBar as

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar(); 
actionBar.hide();
```

Ref [docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html)

Also if your requirement in static, then you can choose a theme for your activity that dos not have actionbar such as

```
android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
```

You can do this as:

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar" 
  android:name=".name_here" 
  android:label="@string/app_name" >
```

Answer (score 0):

use a style without actionbar, also in your splash screen activity java extend Activity and make the splash screen your MAIN activity and in this activity you call an Intent to open your MainActivity after some seconds

```
 <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
    </activity>
        <activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar"
        android:name=".SplashScreen"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Example:
In your SplashScreen activity write this code. This will open your MainActivity after 2 seconds.

```
  new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
  {
    public void run()
    {
      Intent localIntent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, MainActivity.class);
      SplashScreen.this.startActivity(localIntent);
      SplashScreen.this.finish();
    }
  }, 2000L);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the simplest method.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
```

where R.layout.activity_main is replaced by your layout activity e.g. activity_splash