# I want to hide my title bar in my android application

Tags: java, android, xml, hide, title

I tried to hide my `title bar` in my application, with `xml`:

`android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"`

and java too:

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

But when I try to run my application, the android alerts: Unfortunately, `MyProgram` has stopped.

I'm new in android programming, so I don't know, where to search for solution, but if you ask for, I can copy my codes. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: show your crash logs here

Comment: Try to hide action bar http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19545370/android-how-to-hide-actionbar-on-certain-activities

Comment: Add `requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);` before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`

Comment: Post your java code pls

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I found the answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21814825/you-need-to-use-a-theme-appcompat-theme-or-descendant-with-this-activity

Comment: this work for me  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16823049/splash-screen-application-and-hide-action-bar/57533454#57533454